# How to automate data scraping from multiple pages of site where the URL doesn't change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to amass a table in excel by extracting the data on a webpage. The [site](http://www.ndhealth.gov/ehs/foia/spills/) contains 27 pages with data that I would like to lump into one single table in Excel. However, the URL doesn't change from page to page. I watched a YouTube video that used macros and VBA to import tables of data like this for a site that changed URL with each selected table. However, I'm unsure what to do in this situation.

When I inspect the element I see that changing the page is done with this information:

```html
<input name="TextBoxPageIndex" type="text" value="1" id="TextBoxPageIndex" style="width:35px;">
```

The "value" changes with each page number.
I'm not exactly sure how to write this out into a module in VBA, since I am very new to this stuff.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use the Selenium IDE to record a sample set of actions required to navigate through the  pages and scrape the contents of each.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp

Comment: my bad, I didn't know the rules/etiquette.  Updated with a link to selenium's site.